# What lane do captured mercenaries go to in HotS?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Usually mercenary camps are between lanes so it's not obvious which lane they will join once captured.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Heroes Wiki](http://heroesofthestorm.gamepedia.com/Mercenary_camp):

> ...at which point the mercenaries will run to the **nearest lane** and spring into action for the team.

---

[image]

For example, on Cursed Hollow map:

- Grave Golems (yellow) will push the side lanes
- Knights (blue) will push mid lane
- Siege Giants (green) will push side lanes

Answer (score -3):

Mercs camp will join the lane that is nearest their base.